# What is the problem with Glassfish Embedded container?

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey

This is my `pom.xml` (part of it):

```
[...]
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-embedded-glassfish</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
[...]
```

This is the test:

```
public class FooTest extends JerseyTest {
  public FooTest() throws Exception {
    super("com.XXX");
  }
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
  }
  @Test
  public void shouldWork() throws Exception {
  }
}
```

This is what I'm getting in the log:

```
com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.TestContainerException: org.glassfish.embed.EmbeddedException: You must start the server before calling this API method: EmbeddedDeployer.EmbeddedDeployer Constructor.
at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.embedded.glassfish.EmbeddedGlassFishTestContainerFactory$EmbeddedGlassFishTestContainer.stop(EmbeddedGlassFishTestContainerFactory.java:154)
at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.tearDown(JerseyTest.java:312)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[...]
```

When I remove `setUp()` method from the class everything works fine. What's wrong here?

Comment: i think you are missing `super.setUp()` in setup probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `super.setUp();` in setup.

When you remove it it will call its inherited version of `super`. which is fine.

But as you add your own setUp you have overridden the `super's` version .

Answer (score 1):

You are unintentionally overriding its `setUp()` method. Try changing its name to something else, why not say it, `before()`.

The original `setUp()` method invokes test container by calling `TestContainer.start()`. In your case it couldn't do that, because you overrided the method and never made any call to `super.setUp()`. Therefore, its complaining that, `You must start the server.... so and so`.

Comment: @Vincenzo: I said unintentionally, because one would expect `@Override` over it if its intentional. ;D

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, now I see the problem. And it's already fixed :) I up-voted your answer.